# How to javascript regex format split {0}

Tags: javascript

```
var tex=" Merhaba {SicilFromIk_SicilNo|text} sicil numaralı …FromIk_GörevSeviye|input} olduğundan emin olunuz."
```

how to this text regex parse split?

output= `[{SicilFromIk_SicilNo|text},{FromIk_GörevSeviye|input}]`

Comment: What have you tried to solve it on your own?

Comment: "regex to get string between curly braces" results in a lot of answers. You should be able to find your way from there.

Comment: this code try but not working
let asn=[], ls = "Merhaba {SicilFromIk_SicilNo|text} sicil numaralı …FromIk_GörevSeviye|input} olduğundan emin olunuz.";

ls.replace(/\{.*?\}/g, (x,y)=> m.push(y));

console.log(asn);

Answer (score 0):

```
var tex=" Merhaba {SicilFromIk_SicilNo|text} sicil numaralı …FromIk_GörevSeviye|input} olduğundan emin olunuz.";
tex = tex.replace(new RegExp("…", "g"), "{");
let output = tex.match(/\{.*?\}/g);
```